# Measuring average from a scale

Tags: mean

I am not even sure my question makes sense but hoping one of you might see what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a survey which has the following responses: Unhappy, neutral, happy

I am not sure what values to assign these responses to draw out an average % conclusion of the survey responses I have got. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's an "average % conclusion"? What substantive question are you trying to address? What kinds of things do you want to be able to say?

Comment: Arithmetic averages are typically not used in situations like yours. People usually use the median or mode instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gung said in his comment, "average" (i.e. arithmetic mean) does not apply to categorical or ordinal data such as yours.  As @Glen_b said, you need to be clear about what question you are trying to answer.

For example, if you want to answer "What is the most common answer?", then you would use the mode, i.e. the answer with the most number of responses.  If you want to answer "What answer is the most likely, if I draw one survey at random?", then you probably want to use the mode if it is above some threshold.  (Unhappy = 51, Neutral = 50, Happy = 50 is not very strong evidence in favor of calling "Unhappy" the most likely answer.)  If you want to assess the *collective* emotional state of all survey respondents as a group, then you might use the median answer, but this has some problems, because "U = 50, N = 2, H = 50" has the same median as "U = 2, N = 50, H = 2", i.e. both have a median answer of "Neutral".

If, instead, you convert these ordinal categories to ratio-scale numbers, e.g. "Unhappy" = 1, "Neutral" = 2, and "Happy" = 3, you might think that you can then use arithmetic mean or weighted mean, but you can run into problems very quickly.  For example, all three of these cases would have the same mean score of "2":  A) U = 20, N = 20, H = 20; B) U = 0, N = 60, H = 0; C) U = 30, N = 0, H = 30.  In fact, a very large number of cases would result in a score that rounds to "2", even if one of either "Unhappy" or "Happy" were most frequent by a significant margin.

What ever method you choose, just be aware of it's limitations.